# reg expression on OS 10 vs OS 11

Tags: javascript, regex, macos

I have an expression that works great on Chrome and Firefox OS 10, but not safari. On OS 11 it doesnt work on any. It works fine on PC firefox and chrome. Any idea on how to fix?

```js
 const idRegExp = /(?<=home\/|content\/|navbars\/)(\d*)(.*$)/;
```

Comment: RegExp lookbehinds are not implemented in Safari yet.

Comment: But there's no reason why this shouldn't work in Chrome and Safari. They have their own RegExp engines, the OS is irrelevant.

Comment: Use a capturing group and grab the group value upon a match. No need of positive lookbehind.